# How do you format complex numbers for text output in matlab

Tags: matlab, string-formatting

I have a complex number that I want to output as text using the fprintf command. I don't see a formatspec for complex numbers. Is there an easy way to do this?

Using the format spec for fixed-point is only outputting the real part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation of [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) and [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

> Numeric conversions print only the real component of complex numbers.

So for a complex value `z` you can use this

```
sprintf('%f + %fi\n', z, z/1i)
```

for example

```
>> z=2+3i; 
>> sprintf('%f + %fi\n', z, z/1i)
2.000000 + 3.000000i
```

You can wrap it in an anonymous function to get it easily as a string

```
zprintf = @(z) sprintf('%f + %fi', z, z/1i)
```

then

```
>> zprintf(2+3i)

ans =

2.000000 + 3.000000i
```

Answer (score 6):

Address the real and imaginary parts separately:

```
x = -sqrt(-2)+2;
fprintf('%7.4f%+7.4fi\n',real(x),imag(x))
```

or convert to string first with `num2str()`

```
num2str(x,'%7.4f')
```

Comment: I am afraid you might be right. I'm going to see if anyone else has another idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an easy way, but you can write your own format function (the hard way):

```
function mainFunction()
    st = sprintfe('%d is imaginary, but %d is real!',1+3i,5);
    disp(st);

    st = sprintfe('%f + %f = %f',i,3,3+i);
    disp(st);
end

function stOut = sprintfe(st,varargin) %Converts complex numbers.
    for i=1:numel(varargin)
        places = strfind(st,'%');
        currentVar = varargin{i};
        if isnumeric(currentVar) && abs(imag(currentVar))> eps
            index = places(i);
            formatSpecifier = st(index:index+1);
            varargin{i} = fc(currentVar,formatSpecifier);
            st(index+1) = 's';
        end
    end
    stOut = sprintf(st,varargin{:});
end

function st = fc(x,formatSpecifier)
    st = sprintf([formatSpecifier '+' formatSpecifier 'i'],real(x),imag(x));
end
```

This solution suffers from some bugs, (does not handle %2d,%3f) but you get the general idea.

Here are the results:

```
>> mainFuncio
1+3i is imaginary, but 5 is real!
0.000000+1.000000i + 3.000000 = 3.000000+1.000000i
```