# How to print a complex number without percent sign in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

I tried this

```
a = 1+3*%i;
disp("a = "+string(a))
```

I got `a =  1+%i*3` , but what I want is `a = 1. + 3.i`

So is there any method in Scilab to print a complex number without the percent sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to [Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17400319/), you can format the output string by including the real and imaginary parts separately.

```
mprintf('%g + %gi\n', real(a) , imag(a))
```

However, that looks pretty ugly when the imaginary part is negative. I suggest writing a formatting function:

```
function s = complexstring(a)
    if  imag(a)>=0 then
        s = sprintf('%g+%gi', real(a) , imag(a))
    else 
        s = sprintf('%g%gi', real(a) , imag(a))
    end
endfunction
```

Examples:

```
disp('a = '+complexstring(1+3*%i))
disp('b = '+complexstring(1-3*%i))
```

Output:

> a = 1+3i
>   b = 1-3i