# Two formats shows different complex numbers in Octave

Tags: matlab, format, octave, complex-numbers

Complex numbers are differently displayed in Octave depending on the format.
But, I cannot stand with any of the formats (so far).

Here's my code:

```
a = [-0.067000,-0.067000,-0.068000,-0.069000,-0.069000,-0.070000,-0.070000,-0.071000,-0.071000,-0.072000];
Y = fft(a);
  fprintf(comp_print_log,"%s\n",num2str(Y));
  fprintf(comp_print_log,"\n");
  fprintf(comp_print_log,'%7.4f%+7.4fj\n',real(Y),imag(Y));
fclose(comp_print_log);
```

Here's the output of "fft(a)" on command window:

```
>> fft(a)
ans =

 Columns 1 through 8:

  -0.69400 + 0.00000i   0.00331 - 0.00828i   0.00281 - 0.00439i   0.00219 - 0.00277i   0.00169 - 0.00140i   0.00400 + 0.00000i   0.00169 + 0.00140i   0.00219 + 0.00277i

 Columns 9 and 10:

   0.00281 + 0.00439i   0.00331 + 0.00828i
```

Here's the output:

```
-0.694+0i              0.003309-0.008282i       0.002809-0.004392i       0.002191-0.0027674i      0.001691-0.0014001i         0.004+0i              0.001691+0.0014001i      0.002191+0.0027674i      0.002809+0.004392i       0.003309+0.008282i

-0.6940+0.0033j
 0.0028+0.0022j
 0.0017+0.0040j
 0.0017+0.0022j
 0.0028+0.0033j
 0.0000-0.0083j
-0.0044-0.0028j
-0.0014+0.0000j
 0.0014+0.0028j
 0.0044+0.0083j
```

"num2str(Y)" shows the correct results WITHOUT carriage return.
On the other hand, "real(Y),imag(Y)" shows weird results WITH carriage return.
(By the way, what are they???)

I need a solution either:
"num2str(Y)" with carriage return
 or
"real(Y),imag(Y)" with the correct results.

I referred to:
[How do you format complex numbers for text output in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395362/how-do-you-format-complex-numbers-for-text-output-in-matlab)

Comment: Wow, it's been 9 hours since I posted and all I got is only downvote. This world is wonderful. At least, you should give me a comment why you gave me a downvote. (If you downvoted me for the keyword 'matlab', that's a wrong vote because stackoverflow suggested adding it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `num2str` with an array, you will get back a single string that represents that array. If that array is a row vector, you get back a string with one line (it's all one row), if the array is a column vector, you get back one element per line:

```
octave> Y = [-0.694+0i 0.003309-0.008282i 0.002809-0.004392i  0.002191-0.0027674i];

octave> num2str (Y)
ans = -0.694+0i              0.003309-0.008282i       0.002809-0.004392i       0.002191-0.0027674i

octave> num2str (Y')
ans =

  -0.694-0i        
0.003309+0.008282i 
0.002809+0.004392i 
0.002191+0.0027674i
```

---

About your problem with `real` and `imag`, the issue is how arrays get included on the template. All elements in one argument are used in the template before moving to the next argument:

```
octave> printf ("%f %f\n", [1 2 3], [4 5 6])
1.000000 2.000000
3.000000 4.000000
5.000000 6.000000
```

which is why you're getting the wrong answer. It's reading in all the real part before reading the imaginary part.  You need to create an array where those values are interleaved like so (remember, Octave will read down each column):

```
octave> printf ("%f %f\n", [real(Y)' imag(Y)']')
-0.694000 0.000000
0.003309 -0.008282
0.002809 -0.004392
0.002191 -0.002767
```

Comment: I see! The 2nd one perfectly works. (It was a bit tricky for me because apostrophes are needed both inside and outside the square brackets.) The 1st one works on the command window. (Somehow, it doesn't work in printf() or fprintf(); it prints only the first line. ... But, who cares?). Thank you very much!

Comment: @IanHacker if you use `num2str` you get back a string so there's no need to use `printf()` or `fprintf()`. Those functions act on a template.  But you already have a formatted string ready to print, so use `fputs()` instead.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `fputs(comp_print_log,num2str(Y'));` ... In this case, I get only the first line `  -0.694-0i        ` (There are 2 spaces before the number and 8 spaces after the number. In this comment, those spaces are automatically removed ...)

Comment: @IanHacker use fwrite instead of fputs. My mistake.

Comment: Do you mean: `fwrite(comp_print_log,num2str(Y'));`? In this case, I get a bunch of mystical numbers: ' 0000 0000 .... ....-0000 00000000000000.3221.1223638160618390099099004991141199-++++-----0000000000i....i.... 0000 0000 0000 0000 8421 1248 2374 4732 8960 0698 2270 0722 ii41 14ii   ii ii ' Could you please type exactly what you want me to input? Or, you can also leave this trivial problem. I'm already happy with your original answer. I'm still thankful to you.

Comment: @IanHacker I tried it myself and seems like fwrite does not add the newline and also prints column major. You could do 'fwrite (comp_print_log, num2str (Y')')` but then you still won't have newlines so just forget about it.